# How to run mapreduce on hbase scanner result with TableMapReduceUtil

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

My hbase table look like this:

```
    key---------value
    id1/bla     value1
    id1/blabla  value2
    id2/bla     value3
    id2/blabla  value4
    ....
```

There are million of keys that start with id1 and millions of key that start with id2.
 I want to read the data from hbase with mapReduce because there are a lot of keys that starts with the same Id and 1 map per id isn't good enough. I prefer 100 mappers per Id
I want that more than 1 mapper will run on the same scannerResult that has been filtered by id.
I read about TableMapReduceUtil and tried the following:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Job job = new Job(config,"ExampleSummary");
job.setJarByClass(MySummaryJob.class);     // class that contains mapper and reducer

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCaching(500);        // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);  // don't set to true for MR jobs
// set other scan attrs

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
    sourceTable,        // input table
    scan,               // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
    MyMapper.class,     // mapper class
    Text.class,         // mapper output key
    IntWritable.class,  // mapper output value
    job);
```

With map function that will look like this(it should iterate scanner result):

```
public static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable>  {

    private final IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text text = new Text();

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            text.set("123");     // we can only emit Writables...    
            context.write(text, ONE);
    }
}
<br>
```

My questions are:

1. How is it possible that the map function get as input Result and not ResultScanner? I know that the result of the scan can be iterated by ResultScanner that can be Iterated by Result. ResultScanner has list\array of Result isn't it?
2. How can I iterate on the result of the scanner in the map function?
3. How can I control on the number of split this function will do.If it opens only 10 mappers and I want 20 is It possible to change something?
4. Is there simplest way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with #4 in your list:

The default behavior is to create one mapper per region. Therefore, instead of trying to hack the `TableInputFormat` into creating custom input splits based on your specifications, you should first consider splitting your data into 100 regions (and then you'll have 100 mappers pretty well balanced).

This approach improves both your read and write performance, as you'll be less vulnerable to hotspotting (assuming that you have more than one or two region servers in your cluster).

The preferred way to go about this is to pre-split your table (i.e. define the splits on table creation).

Comment: It sounds great but my table already created with 1 region and it's impossible for me now to edit or recreate it.

Comment: You don't need to recreate it. You can just invoke `split` repeteadly from the hbase shell (`help "split"`) -- or region server web UI.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it right.
I split the table with kind of id and then when I will scan the table - in the background it will execute mapreduce with amount of mappers that equals to the amount of regions(splits)?

Comment: Yes; you split your regions until you get to 100: `split 'tablename', "split-key-prefix"` (e.g. `split 'your_table', 'id1/a'`, `split 'your_table', 'id1/b'`, and so on). This will create X+1 regions if you run it X times. When you get to (say) 100 regions and run a M/R job, the number of mappers will be 100 with the standard TableInputFormat.

Comment: addendum: you may want to set `balance_switch true` to make sure your regions will be properly balanced.

Comment: Sounds good I will try it but it will work only for filters that I can do in the scan right?
What do you recommend for filters that cannot be done with the scanner like filter by specific column value? 
To filter by specific column value I need to iterate on all the scanner result. How can I force this operation to open for me 100 mappers?
For example I want all the rows that column number 3 value is "ABC" this splitting doesn't help me because it's can't be done only with scan and force me iterate on the scan result.

Comment: You have no way to create input splits based on such filters (columnX = 'someValue'). That always involves a full table scan that will only return matching values. Splitting your tables helps here as well, since you'll run the scan in parallel on 100 regions.

Comment: The scan will run in parallel on 100 regions but the filter by column value not.
For example if I have table with 5 rows that splited for 5 regions: 1-a 2-b 3-c 4-d 5-e and I want all the rows that the first column in the value is "b". So first I will make the scan and it will be done with 5 mappers and then I will make the filter on the value with 1 mapper that iterate on the scanner result and my question is how can I make the filter on the value with 5 mappers too?